# Рекурсивные generic типы в C#

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Я хотел бы создать экземпляр класса с обобщением, используя в качестве обобщения тип этого класса.

Вот пример:

```
using RecDic = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, RecDic>;
```

К сожалению этот код выдаст ошибку "неизвестный тип RecDic".

Возможно ли такое использование generic-классов в C# и вообще CLR? Если да, то как правильно описывать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно просто описать новый класс как обычно:

```
class RecDic : Dictionary<int, RecDic>
{

}
```

В таком случае у вас не будет всех конструкторов от `Dictionary<T1, T2>`, но если они нужны, то их вручную придется добавить в новый класс.